# how can I let my customer choose the quantities in a bunded product?

Tags: products, bundle

I'm creating a bundled product. I would like to have an option where in the front end a customer can choose the QTY of the each option given.

E.G
we have the choice of charms for an item of jewellery
at the moment by QTY are defaulted at 1 but i would like for them to have the option of adding as many as they like e.g 4 diamond charms 3 tourmalines.. 
added to the same basket- Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

In fact by default it is possible in magento. I am testing in 1.9.x version and with `RWD` theme.

.........................................

[image]

See this: http://demo.easymart.com.au/pillow-and-throw-set.html

You can simply create bundle product and by default it will have qty option.

**NOTE::**

You may want to set price as dynamic for the bundle item. If set fixed, then should test setting each option price separately in bundle products tab (in edit bundle product page). This will make sure if customer chooses more than 1 qty for each item, then price is calculated correctly. I have tested with dynamic and it works perfectly.